# Cannot call service in my index.html file; Django error

Tags: python, css, angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on implementing multiple themes in my web application using bootswatch. The user can choose what css theme they would like to see on the web application by choosing from a pick-list.

I have written a service, kjTheme, to handle this. Ideally, when a user chooses a new theme (say, "Cyborg") in the front-end, my index file will use the line of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" data-ng-href={{ $kjTheme }}"/>
```

To reference my service. My service then references the corresponding css file path (i.e. '/libs/bootswatch/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css').

However, I am running into a Template Syntax Error. 
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '$kjTheme' from '$kjTheme'
And the exception location points to my django\template\base.py

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong, or what I could check to get me on the right path?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to skip the `$`. It is not a valid python symbol. Just use `{{ kjTheme }}`.

Comment: Ashish, I did try that. It didn't give me any errors (awesome), but I didn't seem to be calling the service, either.

I'll keep trying to debug. But thanks for the help, at least I know to avoid the '$' with python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Django not to try to parse the Angular tags. Use [`{% verbatim %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) to do that.

Comment: It was exactly this issue. I can't believe it -- something so simple! Thank you everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Django and AngularJS both use the double brace syntax `{{ variable }}` you will need to escape the double braces at the Django template level so that Django does not try to render your tag

```
data-ng-href="{% templatetag openvariable %} $kjTheme {% templatetag closevariable %}"
```